# Tescafe load URL delays

Tags: javascript, testing, delay, e2e-testing, testcafe

Using the latest Testcafe, through `gherkin-testcafe`:

```
console.log('Before');
await t.navigateTo( page.url );
console.log('After');
```

I'm seeing between 2 and 20 seconds of delay between the two outputs despite the server under test seeming to respond quickly.

During the delay, Chrome shows Testcafe is pointing at `http://localhost:1337/B1tY5nMdM/about:blank`.

dev tools show that during the delay, repeated calls are made to a URI of something like Fe2Box1 (varies every time) with a JSON response of `{"code":"ok","url":""}`. There are no calls made to my service before or during the delay.

I think it is this delay that is causing random test failures, all of which I guess is because I have done something wrong:

```
const selectSelector = Selector( 'select' )
  .withAttribute( 'name', elName )
  .with({
    timeout: this.INITIAL_TIMEOUT_MS,
    visibilityCheck: true,
    boundTestRun: this.t,
  });
await selectSelector();
// The next line sometimes fails
await this.t.expect( selectSelector.exists ).ok();
await this.t.click( selectSelector );
```

The marked line sometimes fails, sometimes passes, apparently depending on the length of the load delay. From the docs though, I thought only the click could fail?

I see this is the latest Chrome, and presume the same is happening in headless chrome, though I obviously can't see the dev tools there...afaik...

```
[954-e2e 13:57]$ testcafe --version
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
0.18.6
```

Comment: There are too many causes that lead to this behavior. If the latest testcafe version (1.1.2 at the moment) still has this behavior, please [submit a new issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and provide the team with a sample to replicate it, so they can examine your scenario and find a suitable solution.

Comment: I had to stop using the framework, but hope to return when it becomes more stable and when the company monitors tagged questions in StackOverflow.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Let us know how we can help you when you get back to using the TestCafe framework. I apologize for missing your question here, on StackOverflow.

Comment: I loved TestCafe, but was pressed for time. IIRC, the problem was an at-the-time unseen proxy in some weird corp network config: I just needed to know my syntax/usage was not the problem. I look forward to using TestCafe again, and wish you guys the best of luck!

Comment: Thank you. We will be happy to see you among our users again!